# libgdx unable to find com/esotericsoftware/tablelayout.gwt.xml on your classpath

Tags: html, gwt, libgdx

I just setup my libgdx game with the gdx-setup-ui.jar today and I have everything setup in eclipse. I thought I would run each application (i.e. desktop, android, and html) to make sure everything is working ok. Unfortunately, I ran into problems with my html application. I am getting this error with a tablelayout.gwt.xml:

[image: Stacktrace]

I have no idea how to solve this problem. Is there a fix for this problem and if anybody knows it could they share? Thanks!

**EDIT**

So even though i fixed the problem by restarting my project, my problem has come back. This time, however, I am too far along in development to just restart my project, or re-setup my project.

Comment: Do you have the gwt SDK installed?

Comment: Are you sure the libgdx jar is in your classpath and the file tablelayout.gwt.xml is inside it? I can find the files in source code thoug @ https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/gdx/src/com/esotericsoftware

Comment: @Benjamin how do you determine if you have the gwt SDK installed?

Comment: Take a look at `window->preferences->Google` if there is the web toolkit with sdk. Else go for the installation -> https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/download

Comment: @BennX I checked to see if the sdk is there and it is.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my old project and created it again using the gdx-setup-ui.jar application and made sure that all the necessary libraries were included.